# how to change default behavior of select and show only selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hi I have a scenario where I want to change the default behavior of my select box.** Suppose I have a select box:

```
<select>
  <option> I am selected Value</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
</select>
```

What I want is  my select box only to show `I am selected value` and Even if I click the select box nothing happens to it i.e its option should not appear. I am using `pointer-events:none;` to make the things working, but problem is it should be clickable, as on its click it need to perform some other event. Basically I have to make it clickable but prevent select behavior. **How to achieve this with css or jquery and also it should be compatible with internet explorer versions.**

> Here is what I am trying:

```css
select {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option> I am selected Value</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: how will you select other option if you hide other option

Comment: on the event's function, have you tried using `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @SuryaPurohit Yes I have tried that too.. It din't worked at all..

Comment: @guradio I dont want to select other options..  oneOption will be selected programmatically and just need to show that and prevent other option to show.

Comment: try mousedown instead of click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS property `pointer-events:none` does not work on older browsers included IE before version 11.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

You could consider instead:

A) The `disable` attribute.

```html
<select disabled>
  <option> I am selected Value</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
</select>
```

B) A JavaScript script which use `.preventDefault()`:

```js
var selector = document.getElementById('selector');
selector.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
});
```

```html
<select id="selector">
  <option> I am selected Value</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
</select>
```

Using jQuery (for maximum compatibility with older browsers):

```js
$('#selector').mousedown(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selector">
  <option> I am selected Value</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @yes definitely, for older browser you could use Jquery, I will edit my answer...

Comment: I checked your javascript approach on IE 11 .. its not working .

Comment: Try the Jquery version

Comment: "The CSS property pointer-events:none does not work on older browsers [...]" --> and then you show JavaScript code written in ES6, which doesn't work in **any** IE version...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel thanks for your comment, you are right, I rewrote it in older version of js.

Comment: @GibboK Thanks for your jquery answer ,it will work for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution, using a wrapper and a pseudo element, and if you use a single colon for the pseudo, which I used here, it works down to IE8.

With this trick, the select behave as normal if you use `onchange` handler etc., and by simply toggle the class `disabled`, it will work as normal `select` does

```css
div.select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.select.disabled:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="select disabled">
  <select>
    <option selected="selected" > I am selected Value</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

If you need a click handler, you simply attach it to the wrapper instead.

```js
/* New browsers */
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('div.select');
    el.addEventListener('click', divSelectClicked);
  });
  
/* IE8 */
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.onload = function() {
    window.attachEvent('onclick', divSelectClicked);
  }
}
function divSelectClicked() {
  console.log('clicked on select wrapper')
}
```

```css
div.select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.select.disabled:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="select disabled">
  <select>
    <option selected="selected" > I am selected Value</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
    <option> Other option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer .

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#selectToDisable").mousedown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("It's working.");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectToDisable">
  <option> I am selected Value</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
</select>
```

```
<select id="selectToDisable">
  <option> I am selected Value</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
  <option> Other option</option>
</select>
```

For binding a click and not allowing the list to open:

```
$("#selectToDisable").mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("It's working.");
    // everything you need to do ie. your function can be written here
})
```

Comment: Added the snippet

Comment: thanks for the nice answer Surya :) Yes it worked too

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').click(function(){alert('s');});
```

```css
select option:not([selected]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select >
<option selected="selected" > I am selected Value</option>
<option> Other option</option>
<option> Other option</option>
<option> Other option</option>
<option> Other option</option>
<option> Other option</option>
</select>
```